# Docker cannot access an external SMTP server

Tags: docker-compose, smtp, docker-network

I have an SMTP server running on a machine outside my machine. From my machine I can reach this server utilizing ping or telnet on server port, it responds. But from inside docker I cannot reach. I've created my docker using docker-compose an set the network to type bridge.

```
networks:
  app_network_bridge:
    driver: bridge
```

How can I reach from docker an outside server? I've checked with ping and telnet and is not reachable.